# How do I move to next record in the database using a button in jsp

Tags: java, html, mysql, database, jsp

So I finally got my information to display in the text bar
but cannot figure out how to move to the next record. Any help would be appreciated.
this is what I have so far

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Displaying Records</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h3>Displaying Records</h3>
    <P>
    <%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    java.sql.Connection connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "***","*******");
    java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.executeQuery("use books");
    java.sql.ResultSet RS = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM books");
    %>



    <%
    if(RS.next())
        {
    %>





       Code: <input type="text" name="Code" value="<%=RS.getString("BookCode") %>"><br>
        Book Title: <input type="text" name="Code" value="<%=RS.getString("BookTitle") %>"><br>
        Book Price: <input type="text" name="Code" value="<%=RS.getString("BookPrice") %>"><br>



    <% 
        } 
    RS.close();
    connection.close();
    %>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put your code into a scriptlet tag, but you can change

```
if(RS.next())
```

to

```
while (RS.next())
```

Comment: `code <script type="text/javascript">
    function next(){

      var book = document.getElementById("code")
    
        }
    
</script> `code` how would i make a function to move to next record?

Answer (score 0):

To move all records in the result set we need to use

```
while(Rs.next()){
```

.....
.........
}

While we execute a query the result after Rs.next() it will point to the first record. So if we need all record from the resultset then we need to use any loop to move a